# Custom field not showing in admin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

As I created custom post type with taxonomy, when I add a new custom field, it is saving in the database but not showing in custom fields. I don't understand how to show the custom field in admin panel.

Comment: Can you add more details? What custom field? Where do you add it?

Comment: I found the solution. custom field not showing the new fields because of I used this hook `add_action( 'load-post.php', 'post_meta_boxes_setup' );` in functions.php file. Now I am using this hook `add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'post_meta_boxes_setup' );` and now I can see the newly added custom fields in admin panel.

Comment: Oh, you meant meta boxes. Ok, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can easily create a meta box without using any plugin and customize it as per our needs:

[here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) is the Wordpress documentation to create a meta box and [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336) is the example to easily implement it with custom post type. Here is the example:

```
<?php
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'meta_box_add_function');;
function meta_box_add_function()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'wporg_box_id',               // Unique ID
        'Custom Meta Box Title',      // Box title
        'wporg_custom_box_html',      // Content callback, must be of type callable
        'post'                        // Post type ['post', 'custom_post_type']
    );
    // You can add multiple boxes like above
}

function wporg_custom_box_html($post){
  echo 'What you put here, show\'s up in the meta box';
}
?>
```

And here you can save the post data using below hook:

```
<?php add_action( 'save_post', 'meta_box_save_function' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good plugin called [Advanced Custom Fields](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for Wordpress. It's very easy to use and features conditional logic for page layouts, post type and much more.